# Langchain Plan Plans answers to questions

Tags: py-langchain

I need to build a langchain agent that plans an answer to a specific question, that requires multiple steps to be answerd. So, the idea (taken from this work: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.04091.pdf), is the following:

1. The agent is faced with a complex question. First, it has to plan an answering strategy, according to the following command:

*Let’s first understand the problem and devise a plan to solve the problem. Then, let’s carry out the plan
to solve the problem step by step.*

2. An LLM agent solves one step at the time, until the last one is solved, and provides the correct answer.

How could i do this in python? Let us assume I'm expecting an output as the following:

**Q**: James decides to run 3 sprints 3 times a week. He runs 60 meters each sprint. How many total
meters does he run a week?

**A**: *Let’s first understand the problem and devise a plan to solve the problem. Then, let’s carry out the plan
to solve the problem step by step.*

*Output:
Given:
James runs 3 sprints 3 times a week.
Each sprint is 60 meters.
Plan:
We need to calculate the total meters run by James in a week.
Calculation:
Total number of sprints run by James in a week = 3 sprints x 3 times = 9 sprints
Total meters run by James in a week = 9 sprints x 60 meters = 540 meters
Answer:
James runs 540 meters in a week.*

Can someone provide me with a guideline on how to build it? Which function to use, how to structure the chain, and an overall intuition of the process?

Thanks!

Comment: More a guideline on how to build it (where to look, functions to use, etc.) Thanks, will update the question